# “Blacklisted address, +50 Spam score” header in mailing: how do I check my originating address?

Tags: email, spam

I just recently took over webmaster/sysadmin duties for a website, and the new owner wants me to send a mass mailing to our clients. (Let me stress this: the recipients are all clients that signed up for the website). I'm doing some tests first by sending to my own email accounts, and I find that Yahoo and Gmail sometimes send my emails to the spam folder. I checked the headers, and I saw this particular one:

```
BlacklistCheck: Blacklisted address, +50 Spam score
```

A few pieces of additional info:

- The domain doesn't show up in any blacklists.
- According to headers, the mail passes SPF, but fails DKIM because there is "no key for signature".
- I am sending the mailings through the mail server associated with the domain. I just checked, and the mail server doesn't show up in any blacklists either.

So, it seems (unless I'm wrong) that all the trouble comes from the email address I'm using as the "From:" header. How can I check whether that address is in any blacklist? All the blacklists I know check just IPs and domains, and as I said, mine comes out clean.

EDIT: here is the zone information of my domain, with the real domains and IPs replaced:

```
mydomain-example.com    mail exchanger = 10 mail.mydomain-example.com.
mydomain-example.com    text = "v=spf1 a mx ip4:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ~all"
mydomain-example.com
    origin = ns39.myhostingprovider.com
    mail addr = hostmaster.mydomain-example.com
    serial = 2017012901
    refresh = 14400
    retry = 3600
    expire = 1209600
    minimum = 86400
```

Comment: +50 points me to dmarc quarantine, do you have any more info?

Comment: What other info would you like to know? (By the way: I tried sending email from another address in the same domain, but the same message appeared in the headers).

Comment: how about your domain or a zone copy (s/mydom/example.com/)

Comment: I just edited my question with more info.

Comment: no dmarc/dkim?   odd